# Can't style object to eliminate scroll bars

Tags: html, object, styles

I'm making an eBay listing whereby I'm embedding a webpage using the following code:

```
<!--[if !IE]> <!-->
<object id="object" type="text/html" data="http://www.taketimetounwind.co.uk"
</object>;
<!--<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE]>
<object id="object-ie" classid="clsid:25336920-03F9-11CF-8FD0-00AA00686F13" data="http://www.taketimetounwind.co.uk"></object>;
<![endif]-->
```

In order to prevent scroll bars, I need to ensure that I style the body of the document containing the code I wish to load dynamically with style="border: 0; margin: 0; overflow: hidden;".

Because I can't include the body tag in the listing, I've tried to use a div tag like so:

```
<div style="border: 0; margin: 0; overflow: hidden;">
<!--[if !IE]> <!-->
<object id="object" type="text/html" data="http://www.taketimetounwind.co.uk"
</object>;
<!--<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE]>
<object id="object-ie" classid="clsid:25336920-03F9-11CF-8FD0-00AA00686F13" data="http://www.taketimetounwind.co.uk"></object>;
<![endif]-->
</div>
```

The scroll bars still appear, however.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't set a height on your div, `overflow: hidden` does nothing. Because the body element is taller than its parent, you'd have to be able to detect the height of the parent element and set your div's height to that. You may need scripting.

The alternative is to use a fixed height, but that's not likely to be a good solution in a mobile world.

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance, would it look like this?

Comment: <div style="height: 1000px; border: 0; margin: 0; overflow: hidden;">

Comment: That's how you'd do the fixed-height option. You probably couldn't go 1000px, though, as most users don't have that much viewport height. For a scripting solution I'd need to know more about the ancestor element arrangement.